# How to convert a list of points in a file to two separate arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, numpy

How to convert a list of points in a file to two separate arrays?

File: data.txt

```
{(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4),(5.5,6.6),(7.7,8.8),(9.9,10),(11,12)}

f = open("data.txt", "r")
print(f.read()) 
sread= f.read() 
f.close()
```

Outputs:

```
>>> print(x)
[1.1 3.3 5.5 7.7 9.9 11]

>>> print(y)
[2.2 4.4 6.6 8.8 10 12]
```

Comment: Please show your attempts at solving this problem

Comment: That's not a list, but a set (and thus should not be expected to remain ordered). Other than that, have you looked at `zip()`?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [(1.1,2.2),(3.3,4.4),(5.5,6.6),(7.7,8.8),(9.9,10),(11,12)]
x = []
y = []
for a,b in list:
    x.append(a)
    y.append(b)
```

Comment: It is a list in string from a file. It is not python list. f = open("data.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
sread= f.read()
f.close()

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?